# How to select all the related fields and filtering the values by these fields

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have the following many-to-many relationship:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS bookmarks (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    title TEXT NOT NULL,
    url TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE
)

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tags (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    name TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE
)

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS bookmarks_tags (
    bookmark_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    tag_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY(bookmark_id) REFERENCES bookmarks(id),
    FOREIGN KEY(tag_id) REFERENCES tags(id)
)
```

I wonder how to do a query to filter bookmarks by tags, but still select all tags.

I have the following query:

```
SELECT title, url, GROUP_CONCAT(tags.name)
FROM bookmarks
LEFT OUTER JOIN bookmarks_tags
    ON bookmarks.id = bookmarks_tags.bookmark_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN tags
    ON bookmarks_tags.tag_id = tags.id
WHERE tags.name = "tag1"
GROUP BY url
```

but if a bookmark has more than one tag, only `tag1` will get returned.

And adding `AND tags.name = "tag2"` in the `WHERE` clauses will return no results.

So how to select all tags while filtering the bookmarks by tags?

Comment: Double quotes in SQL are for names; use single quotes for string literals: `'tag1'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for bookmark *having* at least one tag1 record. You can check this after aggregation in a having clause.

```
SELECT b.title, b.url, GROUP_CONCAT(t.name)
FROM bookmarks b
JOIN bookmarks_tags bt ON b.id = bt.bookmark_id
JOIN tags t ON bt.tag_id = t.id
GROUP BY b.url
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN t.name = 'tag1' THEN 1 END) > 0;
```

Outer joins make no sense here, because you are only interested in bookmarks that do have tags.